# Difference between `present` & `push` ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, dismissviewcontroller

`dismissViewController` method not working to get previous `viewcontoller`

```
[self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

`popViewController` work and go to previous viewcontroller

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

i want to pass data like below please help me.but as i describe `dismissViewController` method not working.

```
 [self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
            HomeVC *loading;
            loading.IdNameLabel.text=display;
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Code" message:display delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert show];
 }];
```

thank in advance.

**Update**

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    self.IdNameLabel.text=self.GetscanResult;
}
```

this method contain in HomeVC.when dismiss `navcontroller` it shows HomeVC.

is upper method can call after dismiss viewcontroller?

**SOLUTION**

this is very stupid question when i am at beginner level.
here is specification about it.
it will depend on method which will you `Present` || `Push` viewController.

Delegate methods will work with protocol delegate method when view controller present.

Comment: what is `GetscanResult`? share that in your question and also the part where you push a viewController. Would like to see that. Have you thought about using delegates?

Comment: @staticVoidMan thank for attending my question i found my solution from delegate method.BTW getscanresult is string and pass on scan button click

Comment: great! cleanest approach is the delegation pattern for such cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method you need to use to go back depends on how you showed the view controller.

The first of the two common ways are by using a navigation view controller to push and pop view controllers off the stack.

The other common way is to present and dismiss a view controller modally.

You cannot for example present a view controller modally, and expect to be able to pop it off from the navigation controller, or vice versa.

Comment: i am passing viewcontroller by navigation controller

Comment: sorry but i didnt get what you say?

Comment: but data not print in textfield can you help me.